# Track and redirect an offsite link using Google Analytics without javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, geolocation, statistics

I have a text file link which needs to be tracked for geo profile of my users, is it possible to have a url which will redirect my users to the correct file and record the stats in Google Analytics without using javascript. For clarity I need something like `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.1.7&utms=1&utmn=1894752493&utmhn=www.mylink.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280×1024&utmsc=24-bit` but with a redirect to the destination page.

I cannot also use any server-side script as the file contains version information about my software and is being accessed thousands of times per second.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Universal Analytics. Write a script that pipes your server log file (the lines relevant to you) to Analytics via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference). Include a queue time parameter (which allows to to record the correct time of the time even if you send it up to four hours after the hit occured). Run the script every few hours.

Alternatively at least the Apache webserver allows to reroute writes to the log file through external processes (via the CustomLog Directive), so you could pipe the hits to GA as they occur in real time.

While this is still a serverside solution it will not generate huge loads in the way calling a redirect script will do.

Comment: The file is being served using Amazon S3 and Cloudflare, this combination makes things a bit more difficult. Amazon S3 sees Cloudflare IP and therefore it's logs are useless.